# to sound down to somebody

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “*The wild gander leads his flock through the cool night,
>   Ya-honk he says, and sounds it down to me like an invitation.”*

Quote by  [Walt Whitman](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9106675-the-wild-gander-leads-his-flock-through-the-cool-night), Song of Myself.

What does the writer mean by "sounds it down to me"?
I can read this sentence in two different ways.
1. It (Ya-honk) sounds - or seems - to him like an invitation.
2. It (the gander) sounds it down like an invitation to him.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t "sound down to someone".  Sounding down to someone means something else entirely. This is transitive, "sound **something** down to someone", in this case an inviting honk.

You just have to parse it. The subject of *sounds* is *he* just as it was of *says*, and the antecedent of *he* is *the wild gander*. The object of *sounds* is *it*, and the antecedent of *it* is *Ya-honk*, which was the object of *says*.

So this simply means:

1. The wild gander leads his flock through the cool night.
2. The wild gander says Ya-honk.
3. The wild gander sounds his Ya-honk down to me like an invitation.

Comment: Ok. But can you say what “sound his Ya-honk down to me” means? Does it mean sends it down to me?

Comment: This is poetry, not prose, and poets are not bound by the rules of grammar. However, we can be fairly certain that the gander (in the sky, above the speaker) sounds (makes a sound) which is heard by the person below, also that, to the hearer, this resembles an invitation in some way.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Where is the “grammatical error” then? There is none.

Comment: Did I say there was an error?

Comment: @Connoisseur Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You said that "poets are not bound by the rules of grammar". Why? What does it have to do with this question or this answer?

Comment: @Connoisseur The meaning of "sounds his honk" is that the gander makes the honking sound. It is similar to the idea that a driver "sounds his horn" or a steamboat captain "sounds his whistle". The word "down" has been added because Whitman was on the ground and the bird was in the air. The phrase "sounds his horn" is a little old fashioned now but when Whitman was writing it was very common.